# Speeding up Inkscape with a hex grid

Tags: inkscape

I'm a fairly inexperienced Inkscape user.  I've added a hex grid with this add-on:

https://github.com/lifelike/hexmapextension/

The grid is roughly 60 hexes across and 50 hexes vertically.

I really like the hex grid . . . but it really really slows Inkscape down.

I am looking for ways to speed up Inkscape particularly while using this hex grid.

I know I can turn off the layer with the hex grid, and that works, but I like having the layer available.

I tried copying the hex grid layer, then combining the objects that make up the hex grid.  It took a ridiculously long time to combine it, but maybe performance is better with it combined.

One thought I had was if I could somehow turn that layer into a bitmap, that that might be faster, but I haven't figured out how to do that or even if that makes much sense with a vector graphics program.

My machine is a 2-year-old Dell XPS laptop with fairly decent hardware:

- Intel i7 CPU
- Intel HD Graphics 530
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
- 32 GB RAM
- 1TB SSD hard drive

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Buy a faster machine? No, there is nothing much you can do except  a smaller grid.

Comment: I tried using the extension on an A4 page with the default settings, but Inkscape doesn't slow down in any noticeable way.   Is the grid you are using huge by any chance? Or perhaps the issue is your computer system?

Comment: I added machine specs and size of hex grid to the question. Thank you.

Comment: How can you guys live with that little hard drive? I have 12 terabytes and still need to buy more next month or so

Comment: LOL.  My needs are quite modest.  Hard to believe, but hard drives were once measured in megabytes.

Comment: @Jack Kilobytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have ever opened the Objects dialog, close it. Close Inkscape. Open Inkscape again. In the 0.92.x series, the objects dialog, if it has ever been opened, slows Inkscape down considerably.
2. If that wasn't the issue, or if it's still too slow, try to reduce the number of objects. Your idea of combining does work.
3. If you don't need to see the hexagons all the time, consider hiding the layer they're in.
4. If you want to hide them, and keep a less good version visible, use the Edit > Make a bitmap copy functionality to make a bitmap copy.
5. It might be that the performance issue is related to something else. If you share your file, we can have a look.

Comment: Thank you.  Good suggestions.  It turns out combining did help substantially.  The others are good to know as well.  Thanks again.